# Display currency in US Dollars

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, currency, cultureinfo

I have a huge ASP.NET Web App with lots of currency fields in multiple view models. The culture of the application is set to en-GB as needed. My requirement is even though the culture is en-GB, currency should always be in US Dollars.

I know I can format the string to display in dollar but is there any way (Data Annotation, may be?) by which I don't have to convert all of those fields in US Dollars before displaying.

One of my view model is as below:

```
    [DisplayName("Price"), DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; } = 1;

    [DisplayName("Discount"), DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public Nullable<decimal> Discount { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public Nullable<decimal> Tax { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Total { get; set; } = 1;
```

Comment: Hello. Are you able to except formatting in the view itself? I know this will essentially convert to US format when rendered, but it leaves the date in GB format through your application.

Comment: Hello, Could you elaborate a bit please, did not get you. I am trying to look for a method where I don't have to convert all these fields in views.

Comment: I don't have a data annotation solution, But I display US format dates from UK dates by specifying a format in the views TextBoxFor. This way you only have to put it in one place and the underlying model data is still in UK format.

Comment: yes I guess you are talking about string.format. I am planning to use it as a last resort. Also thinking of creating editor/display template.

Comment: Yes in essence... ToString("MMM dd yyyy")